# Save shared object in database

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flex4.6

Can we save `SharedObject` in Database if yes then how? I want to save multiple `SharedObject's`  in Database and when I would select from one of them i'll be able to select...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about storing several `SharedObject`'s on the client side, your application can simply create several `SharedObjects`'s, and just postfix them with an index. When you launch your application, you simply just choose which `SharedObject` you want to load. Example:

```
function getSharedObjectFromIndex(index:int):SharedObject {
    return SharedObject.getLocal("foobar"+index.toString());
}

var so:SharedObject;
if ( /*some condition*/ ) {
    so = getSharedObjectFromIndex(0);
}
else {
    so = getSharedObjectFromIndex(1);
}
```

This is not the approach I would take, I would rather save an array holding the different information, and simply save that in one `SharedObject`.

---

If you're talking about storing a `SharedObject` in a database on your server, then you should clarify that in your question.

Comment: thanks @Rasmuas can application give control to user to choose any of saved object?

Comment: @dev that shouldn't be any problem, if you have N different SharedObjects, you could make N buttons, or make the user input a number from 1 to N in some TextField.

Answer (score -1):

What type of object you wanted to store? Yes you can store any type of shared object like image files and can select at any point of time.

Comment: i've saved data in sharedobject... and i'm able to retrieve that but now i want to save two sharedobject for an application.....and when i open application so i choose one of shared object...